# Change the placeholder for image caption in ckeditor and value of image caption when updated on change event should also update alt text of the image

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor for a project I am working on. I checked out the documentation but it's too confusing for me. If anyone can help me here I would really appreciate it. I am trying to update the image caption placeholder and the value of alt text of image when image caption gets updated. Here is the config -

```
CKEDITOR.ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector("#editor"), {
            // https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/toolbar/toolbar.html#extended-toolbar-configuration-format
            toolbar: {
                items: [
                    'exportPDF', 'exportWord', '|',
                    'findAndReplace', 'selectAll', '|',
                    'heading', '|',
                    'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'underline', 'subscript', 'superscript',
                    'removeFormat', '|',
                    'bulletedList', 'numberedList', '|',
                    'outdent', 'indent', '|',
                    'undo', 'redo',
                    '-',
                    'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', '|',
                    'alignment', '|',
                    'link', 'insertImage', 'blockQuote', 'insertTable', 'mediaEmbed',
                    '|',
                    'specialCharacters', 'horizontalLine', '|',
                ],
                shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
            },
            list: {
                properties: {
                    styles: true,
                    startIndex: true,
                    reversed: true
                }
            },
            // https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/headings.html#configuration
            image: {
                toolbar: [
                    'imageStyle:alignLeft', 'imageStyle:alignCenter', 'imageStyle:alignRight', '|',
                    'insertImage', 'resizeImage', '|', 'imageTextAlternative', 'toggleImageCaption', 'linkImage'
                ],
                styles: {
                    options: [
                        'inline', 'alignLeft', 'alignRight',
                        'alignCenter', 'alignBlockLeft', 'alignBlockRight',
                        'block', 'side'
                    ]
                },
                insert: {
                    integration: [
                        'upload',
                        'url'
                    ]
                }
            },
            fontColor: {
                colorPicker: false,
                colors: [
                    {
                        color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 0%)',
                        label: 'Black'
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 30%)',
                        label: 'Dim grey'
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 60%)',
                        label: 'Grey'
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 90%)',
                        label: 'Light grey'
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 100%)',
                        label: 'White',
                        hasBorder: true
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(204, 0, 0)',
                        label: 'Red'
                    }
                ],
                columns: 3
            },
            fontBackgroundColor: {
                colorPicker: false,
                colors: [
                    {
                        color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 0%)',
                        label: 'Black'
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 30%)',
                        label: 'Dim grey'
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 60%)',
                        label: 'Grey'
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 90%)',
                        label: 'Light grey'
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 100%)',
                        label: 'White',
                        hasBorder: true
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(204, 0, 0)',
                        label: 'Red'
                    }
                ],
                columns: 3
            },
            mediaEmbed: {
                toolbar: ['resizeImage', 'mediaEmbed']
            },
            heading: {
                options: [{
                        model: 'paragraph',
                        title: 'Paragraph',
                        class: 'ck-heading_paragraph'
                    },
                    {
                        model: 'heading3',
                        view: 'h3',
                        title: 'Heading 3',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading3'
                    },
                    {
                        model: 'heading4',
                        view: 'h4',
                        title: 'Heading 4',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading4'
                    },
                    {
                        model: 'heading5',
                        view: 'h5',
                        title: 'Heading 5',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading5'
                    },
                    {
                        model: 'heading6',
                        view: 'h6',
                        title: 'Heading 6',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading6'
                    }
                ]
            },
            // https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/editor-placeholder.html#using-the-editor-configuration
            placeholder: 'Content area',
            // Be careful with the setting below. It instructs CKEditor to accept ALL HTML markup.
            // https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/general-html-support.html#enabling-all-html-features
            htmlSupport: {
                allow: [{
                    name: /.*/,
                    attributes: true,
                    classes: true,
                    styles: true
                }]
            },
            // https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/link.html#custom-link-attributes-decorators
            link: {
                decorators: {
                    addTargetToExternalLinks: true,
                    defaultProtocol: 'https://',
                    toggleDownloadable: {
                        mode: 'manual',
                        label: 'Downloadable',
                        attributes: {
                            download: 'file'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            // The "super-build" contains more premium features that require additional configuration, disable them below.
            // Do not turn them on unless you read the documentation and know how to configure them and setup the editor.
            removePlugins: [
                // These two are commercial, but you can try them out without registering to a trial.
                // 'ExportPdf',
                // 'ExportWord',
                'CKBox',
                'CKFinder',
                'EasyImage',
                // This sample uses the Base64UploadAdapter to handle image uploads as it requires no configuration.
                // https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/image-upload/base64-upload-adapter.html
                // Storing images as Base64 is usually a very bad idea.
                // Replace it on production website with other solutions:
                // https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/image-upload/image-upload.html
                // 'Base64UploadAdapter',
                'RealTimeCollaborativeComments',
                'RealTimeCollaborativeTrackChanges',
                'RealTimeCollaborativeRevisionHistory',
                'PresenceList',
                'Comments',
                'TrackChanges',
                'TrackChangesData',
                'RevisionHistory',
                'Pagination',
                'WProofreader',
                // Careful, with the Mathtype plugin CKEditor will not load when loading this sample
                // from a local file system (file://) - load this site via HTTP server if you enable MathType.
                'MathType',
                // The following features are part of the Productivity Pack and require additional license.
                'SlashCommand',
                'Template',
                'DocumentOutline',
                'FormatPainter',
                'TableOfContents',
                'PasteFromOfficeEnhanced'
            ]
        }).then(newEditor => {
            const news = {!! json_encode($news) !!};
            const newsContent = news.hasOwnProperty('content') && news.content;
            const wordCountPlugin = newEditor.plugins.get( 'WordCount' );
            const wordCountWrapper = document.getElementById( 'word-count' );

            wordCountWrapper.appendChild( wordCountPlugin.wordCountContainer );
            editor = newEditor;
            editor.setData(newsContent);

            newEditor.model.document.on('change:data', e => {
                const selectedElement = e.source.model.document.selection.getSelectedElement();
                console.log(selectedElement);

                if(selectedElement && selectedElement.name === 'imageBlock') {
                    newEditor.execute('toggleImageCaption', { focusCaptionOnShow: true });
                }
            });
        });
```

Here I can't figure out how to get the image caption element to update the placeholder and trigger on change event for caption